# command-line Appstore upload

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, app-store-connect

So, since Apple introduced its own Testflight testing service, we need to automate the build and upload process for the sake of continuous integration. However, I can't find any scripts or methods of build an archive and uploading it to iTunes via command-line. Is it possible at all atm?

Answer (score 0):

There's no public iTunes upload API, the only tool under active development I know about is [Nomad CLI](http://nomad-cli.com/) - the [Shenzen](https://github.com/nomad/Shenzhen) module supports uploading to iTunes Connect, through (AFAIK) undocumented APIs.

Comment: As an additional note: you can still use the old TestFlightApp for CI (or Hockey app and other deployment services) and do the new Apple TestFlight uploads manually - the new Test Flight doesn't have a public API AFAIK and has a daily upload limit too which makes it unsuitable for CI